# centos 7 dual display not recognizing

Tags: centos, nvidia

I have a fresh centos7 installation, i installed dkms, i updated the kernel, installed elrepo. I have tried using nvidia-detect, and then installing the proper yum packages for kmod-nvidia&(nvidia-detect).
I have also removed that, and installed drivers directly from nvidia's website for my card.
Both successfully installed the drivers, but will NOT recognize the second monitor no matter what. I tried going into system settings -> displays, and the second monitor simply won't show up.
Both methods rebooted successfully, and the nvidia-server settings shows up, but again, no second monitor.
Any ideas? 
I have centos7, an asus mainboard, i7 CPU, and an nvidia geforce-gt730 card.

I keep searching the internet and all i keep finding is people saying to go into the system settings -> displays, but again, the second monitor does not show up there!
Any help would be appreciated, i have only been using linux a few months now.

Comment: Have you connected the undetected second monitor to the card, or into the motherboard? If the latter, the motherboard's integrated GPU may be disabled by default when a discrete GPU card is detected. If possible, you should connect both displays to the card; if that's not possible, you may have to change some (potentially cryptically named) BIOS setting to allow the iGPU to start even when another GPU is present.

Answer (score 0):

Check the available ports with:

`xrandr -q`

Example to enable both displays (replace ports with your own)

`xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary --auto  --output LVDS1  --auto`